# Should business logic ever be in the model? (MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a class called "Stores" in my MVC app that has a class called "IsInCompliance" which depends on the values of several other fields.  The logic would go through and say "if this, this, and this is true, then IsInCompliance is true".

Should this belong in the model definition, or would this logic be better placed in a service layer or controller?  I figure I have four options:

1. Logic contained in a method within the model
2. Logic contained in a controller that writes back to the model
3. Logic contained in a Service that the model calls
4. Logic contained in a Service that the controller calls

Which is best?  If 3 is the best, isn't there a circular dependency there (since my model project depends on the services project, which depends on the model project)?

Comment: it depends on the logic. if it's looking at properties on itself, then i'd go with option 1. if its logic looking at other classes, then it should be option 4.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/09/17/second_2d00_post.aspx - Hope this will b helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 4 is the correct approach.

Controllers should act as a thin "traffic control" layer and delegate all logic to a service layer beneath them (or if it's not too obvious logic, to a business layer - but that's a different architectural question).

Your model should generally be a pure POCO structure, with optionally micro-logic of things that are internal to the data model. For example, ID generation and data integrity operations.

Most of your logic (for relatively simple / CRUD-based apps) should generally reside in the Service Layer.

Comment: +1 For Ofer Zelig. Generally this pattern is common and fits many solid design approaches.  I use a COntroller=> Service Layer=> Repository.   Model is referenced in Service and repository.  The use of same model in MVC is a discussion point.  But is often done. The model contains logic that manages properties and performs checks and rules that are possible without reference to other objects.

Comment: Putting all of your logic in services will lead to an anemic domain model. http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html

Comment: You are right @RikLeigh and that's why I said _Most_ of your logic and framed that to _relatively simple / CRUD-based apps_. Where you have real business scenraios - trees, decisions, workflow, arithmetic etc. you should probably put them in another layer, be it what they call "Business Layer" or "Domain Model".

Comment: @RikLeigh I think I have addressed what you've written (see my previous comment), so please cancel your downvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of preference/style, but I have always believed that methods that are germane to the Model object belong in that object.

Take this as an example (I'm coding on the fly without an open VS.NET instance, so please forgive any syntax errors, just trying to use this as a vehicle for communication):

```
public class Person 
{
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }

    public bool IsEligibleToEnterLegallyBindingContract() 
    {
        return Age >= 18;
    }
 }
```

I would assert that a model object that contains methods that introspects its own properties and is not dependent on messages and/or properties of other model objects is good object design and a good modeling approach in an MVC environment.

**Update** I had a discussion with a colleague regarding this, and he pointed me toward the [Anemic Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html), an excellent article by Martin Fowler.  I read this article several times after my colleague recommended it.

The closing paragraph from Mr. Fowler's article (this is a direct quote from martinfowler.com and credit is acknowledged and given to that site):

*"In general, the more behavior you find in the services, the more likely you are to be robbing yourself of the benefits of a domain model. If all your logic is in services, you've robbed yourself blind."*

Answer (score 0):

MVC is all about separating concerns. Keep it that way. Separate your logic from your data by placing your business logic in a separate class (layer).

Answer (score 0):

Usually I perform actions on the Model rather than IN the Model, however it is sort of a personal preference. 
I would (in your case) write the logic in the Service layer, then do a coordination call from the Controller that would work on the Model.
That said however, I believe some people refer to this as an [Anemic Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html).

I don't think any of the approaches are wrong, but I personally would go for Number 4.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on your coding style.

Either option 1, or option 4 is correct depending on who you ask.

For something like this, i think option 1 is correct.

If IsInCompliance only depends on the value other properties in the model then it should be in the model.

If the value of IsInCompliance depends on other classes then yes it should be in a service layer.

Moving stuff like this to a service layer results in an Anemic Domain model where your model classes end up just being dto's

In object oriented design, this is considered an anti pattern.

There is still plenty of stuff that needs to be in a service layer, i just don't think this is one of them.